# Migration Error loading Realm database

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to load realm database file from **/res/raw** folder but I get an error.

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
```

Using the following code:

```
private void loadRealmDB() {

        RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .name(REALM_DATABASE_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(configuration);
        Realm.getInstance(configuration).close();

        loadRealmFromRawFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default0), REALM_DATABASE_NAME);

//         You can then manually call Realm.migrateRealm().
        try {
            Realm.migrateRealm(configuration, new RealmMigration() {

                @Override
                public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
                    oldVersion++;
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ignored) {
//            If the Realm file doesn't exist, just ignore.
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Error migration");
        }

        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);

        Log.wtf(TAG, "->>PData size: " + realm.where(PData.class).findAll().size());
        Log.wtf(TAG, "->>SData size: " + realm.where(SData.class).findAll().size());
    }



    public void loadRealmFromRawFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
        long startTime,endTime,resultTime;

        //start time
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), fileName);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end time
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        resultTime = endTime - startTime;
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Bundling realm from R.res.raw: " + resultTime);
    }
```

In the other test project this code works! what could be the problem?

How can i skip migration if i dont need it?

Comment: @HamidrezaShokouhi How can it solve my problem?

Comment: RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                                 .Builder(context)
                                 .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                 .build()

Comment: if i set deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()  i cannot get my data from realm,  realm count == 0.

Comment: Why aren't you using `assetFile` in your configuration instead of this open close delete replace open hack? Anyways, if your schema classes are mismatched from the Realm you're trying to open, you'll have to define a migration.